# MLE of non-numerical variables?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, maximum-likelihood

I know how to find the MLE in the usual case where the variable takes numerical values. But what if that is not the case?

Suppose we have a sample of the blood type of $1000$ independent individuals

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Blood Type} & \text{O} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{AB}\\
\hline
\text{Frequency} & 400 & 250 & 250 & 100 \\
\end{array}
$$

And we are given the probabilities
$$ \Bbb P(X_i=x_i)=
\begin{cases}
(1-p)^2 &, & x_i=\text{O} \\
p(1-p) &, & x_i=\text{A} \\
p(1-p) &, & x_i=\text{B} \\
p^2 &, & x_i=\text{AB} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Where $X_i$ is the blood type of the $i$-th individual. How do we find the MLE?

In a Bernoulli distribution, we would say that

$$ \Bbb P(X_i=x_i)=
\begin{cases}
1-p &, & x_i=0 \\
p & , & x_i=1
\end{cases}
=p^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}$$
Do we use some sort of a similar idea in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps delete here and ask at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: The likelihood function for a discrete distribution does not care what the objects actually are, if you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x; p) = \mathbb P(X = x)$ denote the probability mass function and $x_1,\dotsc, x_n\in\{O, A, B, AB\}$ denote the realizations. 
Then, we obtain the log-likelihood function
$$ \begin{align*} 
L(p) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \log(f(x_i; p)) \\
&= 500 \cdot 2 \cdot \log(1-p) + 2\cdot 250 \cdot (\log(p)+ \log(1-p)) + 100 \cdot 2 \cdot \log(p) \\
&= 1500 \log(1-p) + 700 \log(p).
\end{align*}
$$

Now, differentiate $L$ to maximize it for $p\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Likelihood can be written as:
\begin{align}
L(p;\mathbf{X})=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p)^{2\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=O\}}}[p(1-p)]^{\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=A\  \cup\  X_i=B\}}} p^{2(1-\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=O\}}-\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=A\  \cup\  X_i=B\}})}
\end{align}
I know nobody is willing to read that, so define:
\begin{align}
\alpha_i:=\alpha_i(X_i):=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=O\}},\ \ \ \ \ \   \beta_i:=\beta_i(X_i):=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=A\  \cup\  X_i=B\}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\alpha:=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i, \ \ \ \ \ \beta:=\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i
\end{align}
I hope it is not confusing. So we can write the Likelihood now as:
\begin{align}
L(p;\textbf{X})=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p)^{2\alpha_i}[p(1-p)]^{\beta_i}p^{2(1-\alpha_i-\beta_i)}
\end{align}
We keep writing $L(p;\mathbf{X})$ even though no $X_i$ appears in RHS. That is just to let you know that there is still $X_i$ hidden somewhere in the expression, namely in $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.

One rather works with the log-likelihood $l(p;\textbf{X})$ and that is:
\begin{align}
l(p;\textbf{X})&=\sum_{i=1}^n 2\alpha_i \log(1-p)+\beta_i\log(p(1-p))+2(1-\alpha_i-\beta_i)\log(p)\\
&=(2\alpha+\beta)\log(1-p)+(2n-2\alpha-\beta)\log(p)
\end{align}

Notice that $\lim_{p\to 0^+} l(p;\mathbf{X})=\lim_{p\to 1^-}l(p;\mathbf{X})=-\infty$. Moreover if there is only one stationary point for $p\in (0,1)$ then that must be *the* global maximum (why?).

We will check the stationary points. So we solve $l'(p;\textbf{X})=0$:
\begin{align}
(2\alpha+\beta)\frac{1}{1-p}+(2n-2\alpha-\beta)\frac{1}{p}=0
\end{align}
Or:
\begin{align}
p(2\alpha+\beta)+(2-2\alpha-\beta)(1-p)=0
\end{align}
Or:
\begin{align}
p=\frac{2\alpha+\beta-2}{4\alpha+2\beta-2}
\end{align}
Substitute everything back to finish.